# Python: Is there a way to search a directory for all files that contain a given string in the name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, search, directory, find

I'm new to Python and need to search a directory for a specific file given part of the name. For example I have a folder full of many different files:

```
 folder:
      file1_dogname.html
      file1_catname.html
      file2_othername.html
```

and I need to ask the user which file to open, the options can only be dog, cat, or other. If the user says "dog", I need it to find the file named "file1_dogname.html". Is this possible? Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: What is your exact question: how to accept user input?  how to restrict user input to a given set of choices?  how to assemble a filename from known parts?  how to open a file?

Comment: You can use `glob.glob` or if you want to do a case insensitive compare, a combination of `os.listdir` and `fnmatch.fnmatch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at these libraries (you may not even need a library*):

1. glob
2. fnmatch

There are a lot of ways to do this! 
The best way to learn is to try it out yourself! :)

Here are a few references :

https://pymotw.com/2/glob/

https://www.poftut.com/python-glob-function-to-match-path-directory-file-names-with-examples/

Happy learning!